# how to set default actions in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

if i have the following

Url.Action("Index", "Settings");

How do ensure that the url is alway

"Settings/Index" and not "Settings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `action = "Index"` from your routing table in Global.asax.